# NSMutableDictionary isKindOfClass NSDictionary is false

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsdictionary

Why is the following code snippet ONLY printing blah3 and blah4, but not blah2?

`isKindOfClass` is supposed to respect inheritance, but it appears to be failing exactly that.

Obj-C:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary new];
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];

if([dict isKindOfClass:[mutableDict class]]){
    NSLog(@"blah"); //does not print (as expected)
}

if([mutableDict isKindOfClass:[dict class]]){
    NSLog(@"blah2"); //does not print (unexpected!)
}

if([mutableDict isKindOfClass:[mutableDict class]]){
    NSLog(@"blah3"); //prints
}

if([dict isKindOfClass:[dict class]]){
    NSLog(@"blah4"); //prints
}
```

Swift:

```
var dict = NSDictionary()
var mutableDict = NSMutableDictionary()
if(dict.isKindOfClass(mutableDict.dynamicType)) {print("blah")}
if(mutableDict.isKindOfClass(dict.dynamicType)) {print("blah2")} 
if(dict.isKindOfClass(dict.dynamicType)) {print("blah3")}
if(mutableDict.isKindOfClass(mutableDict.dynamicType)) {print("blah4")}
```

Using Xcode 7.3.1, iOS 9.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is, `NSDictionary.new` is not guaranteed to return an `NSDictionary` itself - it can return a subclass of it. And your dict happens to be of a subclass like `NSDictionary0`. Also, the mutable one is probably of a subclass of `NSMutableDictionary`, like `NSMutableDictionaryM`.

So your `NSMutableDictionary` is indeed a `NSDictionary`, but not it's not inheriting from that other subclass.

You can easily check with `isKindOf:[NSDictionary class]` instead. You might want to dump or inspect the classes of your concrete objects and be surprised.

Edit: here's a quick and dirty class diagram:
[image]

As you can see, one is not "kind of" another, although both are `NSDictionary`.

This is called a "class cluster" and has some tricky implications. `NSString` is another famous one where the classes rarely are what newcomers expect.

Comment: Not sure what you're saying. If NSMutableDictionary is an NSDictionary, why wouldn't blah2 print?

Comment: Because you are comparing against `dict.class`. But dict is not `NSDictionary`, but a subclass thereof.

Comment: How about the usecase where I have two id's and I want to check if the classes are the same or a subclass. In that case I need to use isKindOfClass. I can't compare directly to [NSDictionary class]. This is the purpose of isKindOfClass, no?

Comment: @Eiko From the docs: "*YES if the receiver is an instance of aClass **or an instance of any class that inherits from aClass**, otherwise NO.*"https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418511-iskindofclass

Comment: @AMomchilov And your point is? It's working just as expected.

Comment: @Eiko `NSMutableDictionary` is a subclass of `NSDictionary`, thus `isKindOf` will return `true` and `blah2` should be printed.

Comment: @user1366911 That information would be completely useless, as those classes would have a common anchestor, but they are not inheriting from each other either way.

Comment: @AMomchilov But he is not comparing against [NSDictionary class]. He is comparing against [dict class]. And dict ist not NSDictionary itself. It is a subclass of it, which is *NOT* in the hierarchy of NSDictionary. Just do NSLog("%@", dict.class); and see yourself!

Comment: @Eiko Wow, you're right. 

    NSLog(@"%@ - %@ - %@ - %@", [dict class], dict.superclass, [mutableDict class], mutableDict.superclass);`
`__NSDictionaryI - NSDictionary - __NSDictionaryM - NSMutableDictionary`

Comment: @Eiko Oooooooh yes, I see what you mean. Nice catch!

Comment: Eiko, if you clear up your answer I'll accept yours, instead of the guy who's more clear but just duplicated yours.

Comment: It's only a duplicate because it's the correct answer. If you make yours clearer I'll remove mine.

Comment: Added some more explanation and a graph.